# Why does this ssh tunnel command give an error on Mac but not Linux?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, ssh-tunneling, macos

I was trying to tunnel a psql connection through a remote login server to a postgres database server, and I encountered some kind of difference in the way the arguments are parsed that led to a period of debugging hair-pulling.

On a Linux computer with bash 5.0.11 and OpenSSH_8.1p1, I can successfully do this using these commands in different consoles:

```
ssh -N -T -L 50000:pgsql96.database.server:5432 user@remote.login.server

psql -h localhost -p 50000 -d databasename -U user
```

On a Mac computer with bash 3.2.57 and OpenSSH_7.9p1, when I run the same tunneling command

```
ssh -N -T -L 50000:pgsql96.database.server:5432 user@remote.login.server
```

I get the following error

> Bad local forwarding specification '50000:pgsql96.database.server:5432 user@remote.login.server'

Eventually, I realized that there must be a difference in command line argument parsing because the above string quotes the remote login server in the forwarding, and I fixed the command by adding `--`:

```
ssh -N -T -L 50000:pgsql96.database.server:5432 -- user2@remote.login.server
```

Why are these arguments parsed differently between these two versions, and when should I expect this difference in behavior to occur?

Comment: Does `man ssh` on each machine shed any light on the difference?

Comment: @roaima It did not, but I am also not sure what I should look for.

Comment: Please make sure it's not this issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235201

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, not that issue. Command was typed on the Linux machine, sent to Mac via email, then cut and pasted into command line.

Comment: @mattm can you type the command (not paste it). What happens?

Comment: The forwarding specification worked for me as typed above with OpenSSH_7.9p1 and bash 3.2.57(1) on a mac.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Succeeded. That is most curious and highly irritating. Also, I am not the user of the Mac, who has now left for the day.

Comment: So probably a weird space (not a space), as @KamilMaciorowski said.

Comment: Different versions, different (build) configurations, different (run time) configuration? Different network connections?